# Leap Motion + OSGi : "Problematic Frame" error in native code after several event receptions

Tags: java, osgi, leap-motion

I've got a pretty big OSGi project and I'm trying to add some Leap Motion integration to it.

I can interact with Leap Motion in OSGi as explain by [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858647/exception-access-violation-when-accessing-leapmotion-api-within-osgi). Now, when I do the same things and try to interact with Leap Motion from my project bundle, I do receive several leap events and eventually the JVM crashes with the following native code error:

```
  # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
  # 
  #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000, pid=7492, tid=5696 
  # 
  # JRE version: 6.0_30-b12 
  # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 ) 
  # Problematic frame: 
  # C  0x00000000
```

I don't understand why the native code crashes after several notifications have been sent to  my *com.leapmotion.leap#onFrame(Controller)*. I do nothing between the first notification and the moment the library crashes. It's weird...

FYI, my project bundle contains no other native libraries.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Man, you really not having a lot of luck. This error indicates an error in the JNI code, theoretically this is not something you can help, it is in Leap Motion's code. It looks like it is jumping to 0. There must be some hidden assumption. Try running this in the debugger and set a breakpoint on all exceptions, maybe that can shed some light.

Comment: Are you talking about Java exceptions (within my Java IDE) or exceptions within the .dll (using some C/C++ IDE which I do not master)?

Comment: First look at all Java exception, my suspicion is that some Java code is supposed to set some variable, a string for example, and this is not done because it runs into an OSGi fence. But I am guessing. Got my leap motion controller 5 mins ago :-) Google Earth was a disappointment though :-(

Comment: Maybe something to do with invalid frames? [Frame.isValid()](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Java/API/classcom_1_1leapmotion_1_1leap_1_1_frame.html#a895c3c63566e8987a11fcaee4f875829)

Comment: Two educated guesses: 1. There's a bug in the current SDK that can cause a crash when you access the Hand.frame() function. 2. The Leap libraries are multi-threaded, each notification is called on a separate thread, which can cause unexpected behavior, especially in complex projects. If you poll the Controller object for frames instead of using the Listener callbacks, you can avoid threading issues.